# Bridge between 64-bit and 32-bit application

Tags: c#, .net

What would be the best (easiest and fastest) way to provide an access between 64-bit application (ASP.NET) and 32-bit assembly (.NET 32-bit database driver).

1) I've got complete control over this two pieces of code (64-bit and 32-bit),
2) They both run on the same machine,
3) Security is not an issue,
4) Performance is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the ASP.NET application processes in 32-bit mode.  This is the only way to get it to work.

For example, Crystal Reports XI does not have a 64-bit driver.  In order to run the report, you must run the ASP.NET app in 32-bit mode on a 64-bit server.

On IIS 6.0:

> Click Start, click Run, type cmd, and
>   then click OK.
>
> Type the following command to enable
>   the 32-bit mode:
>
> **cscript %SYSTEMDRIVE%\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/AppPools Enable32bitAppOnWin64 1**
>
> Now since the IIS worker process is
>   running in 32 bit mode we need to
>   ensure the ASP.NET ISAPI filter is
>   also changed to the 32 bit version.
>
> Type the following command to install
>   the version of ASP.NET 2.0 (32-bit)
>   and to install the script maps at the
>   IIS root and under:
>
> **%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe –i**

In IIS 7.0, you can set the 32 or 64-bit per application pool whereas on IIS 6.0 it's the entire processes of the server.

Comment: We do this to be compatible with the Oracle client installed on our machines.

Comment: ODP 11g now has a 64-bit optional download/patch.  :)

the ODP package even includes ODAC for you: http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html

Comment: ...But you're still up the creek with Crystal :(

Comment: Thanks Jonathan,
Where can I find 64-bit version of ODP 11g?

Comment: The link is in the comment above.